# Cordova app in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, cordova, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am totally new to Cordova and also in general to Apps. I have a App which was developed in Cordova. The project is in VSTS. How do i open the cordova project from VSTS to Visual Studio 2017?

Thank you in advance for all your support!

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, Thank you! It was really helpful. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the Visual Studio is supported Cordova project ([Installing Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation?view=toolsforcordova-2017)), but you need to check whether your project can be opened through Visual Studio (e.g. project file). 
Secondly, refer to these steps to map the files to your local machine:

TFVC:

1. Open Team Explorer > Click manage connections icon button > Manage connection link > Connect to project >Select corresponding VSTS team project> Connect
2. After connecting to your VSTS team project > Click Home icon button > Source Control Explorer
3. Find out your project and select the folder > Click Not mapped link > Specify Local folder > Map > get files
4. Coding
5. Right click the solution/project/file > Check in to submit the changes to VSTS

Git:

1. Open Team Explorer > Click manage connections icon button > Manage connection link > Connect to project> Select corresponding VSTS team project> Select corresponding repository> Specify path (local path) > Clone
2. Coding
3. Right click solution/project/file > Commit > Commit all
4. Click Sync > Push to submit changes to your VSTS